# R SurvSplit survival with Propensity Score Matched groups

Tags: survival, propensity-scores

I am looking to perform a SurvSplit of the survival r-package. The difficulty that I have is that I would like to perform the SurvSplit on two matched groups (full Propensity Score Matching). So I have weights and cluster that need to become apparent in the SurvSplit function somewhere.

If anyone has another idea, I am happy to hear them. Thank you.